# Have Java variables at MySQL query limit clause

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing this program in Java and I am trying to execute this query but there is a syntax error. can anyone tell where the problem is? thanks

```
int initial;
int last;
this.initial=initial;
this.last = limit;
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from weibo_olympics Limit '"+initial+"','"+last+"';");
```

Comment: Offset and size in the `LIMIT` clause should not be enclosed within single quotes, since they need to be numeric. Remove them like `Limit "+initial+","+last+""`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
int initial;
int last;
this.initial=initial;
this.last = limit;
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from weibo_olympics Limit "+initial+","+last);
```

Hope this help